# grep with after-context that does not contain a keyword

Tags: perl, shell, unix, grep

I want to grep through logs, and gather a certain exception stacktrace but I want to only see those that do not contain certain keywords in --after-context.
I do not know in which line in after-context the keyword is.

Simple example - given this shell code:

```
grep -A 2 A <<EOF
A
B
C 
R
A
Z
Z
X
EOF
```

the output is:

```
A
B
C 
--
A
Z
Z
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
A
Z
Z
```

I want to exclude any match that has 'B' in after-context

How do I do this? Using grep is not a requirement, though I only have access to coreutils and perl.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, voting to move to http://superuser.com/ OR you can 'flag' it and ask for a moderator to move i. (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: are you from wikipedia? shell _is_ programming (perl too)

Comment: Disagree - this is a question about how to use particular shell programming tools.  And this is categorically not about things requiring super-user privileges, so SuperUser is not appropriate.

Comment: this is sad, people with 30k+ reputations, would not consider this as **software tools commonly used by programmer**

Comment: this is not a question on how to use grep, this is a question how to do stuff, with grep used as an example.
anyways, there are lots of questions about grep on SO, and there even is <gasp> a tag named grep. please go back to wikipedia

Comment: also, from faq:  
*  software tools commonly used by programmers
    practical, 
* answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a good fit for `awk`:

```
 grep -A2 A LOG_FILE | awk -v RS='--\n' '!/B/ { printf "%s", $0 }'
```

- `-v RS='--\n' sets the record separator.
- `!/B/` finds records that do not contain `B`.

Comment: I've tried all the proposed solution. This is, indeed, the best!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
sed -ne '/A/{N;N;/\n.*B/d;p;i --' -e '}'
```

It seems to do what you need, except for the trailing `--`.

Answer (score 0):

This is in perl.

```
use strict;
my $Data = join '',<DATA>;

while( $Data =~ /(A\s+\w\s+\w)/msg ) {
    my $Match = $1;
    next if $Match =~ /B/;
    print $Match;

}

__DATA__
A
B
C 
R
A
Z
Z
X
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $pushok = 0;
my @group;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( m/A/ ) {
        $pushok = 1;
        push @group, $_;
        next;
    }
    if ( m/B/ ) {
        $pushok = 0;
        @group  = ();
        next;
    }
    $pushok and push @group, $_;

    if ( @group == 3 ) {
        print +(join "\n", @group), "\n";
        $pushok = 0;
        @group  = ();
    }
}
__DATA__
A
B
C 
R
A
Z
Z
X
AAA
BBB
AAA
XXX
XXX
```

Which would produce:

```
A
Z
Z
ZZZ AAA
XXX
XXX
```